# Does catch block not get executed if 'onRejected' function is provided for 'then' block in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Newbie in Promises here.

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) (as in the below image) tells it internally calls the `onRejected` function of catch block itself. So is there any use of having a catch block in a Promise if then is being provided with both the functions?

I tried throwing an error using `throw 'error'` and even `Promise.reject('error')` in the then block neither of which triggered the catch block.

Here's the sample code.

```
actionPromise = Promise.reject('error')  // or throw 'Error'
actionPromise
      .then(
        (response) => next({ ...rest, response, type: SUCCESS }),
        (error) => next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE })  // <--- Gets triggered
      )
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('MIDDLEWARE ERROR:', error);  // <--- Not getting triggered
        next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE });
      });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any use of having a catch block in a Promise if then is
> being provided with both the functions?

If you provide the promise rejection handler to the `then()` method, then that handler will execute only if the promise, on which `then()` method is called on, gets rejected.

Error handler passed to the `then()` method is also not invoked if you throw an error from the same `then()` method's fulfilment handler.

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
Promise.resolve(123)
.then(
  val => { throw val },
  error => console.log("inside error handler of first then")
)
.catch(error => console.log("inside catch method"));
```

It is different to the `catch()` method because `catch()` method will handle the promise rejection of any promise that come before it in the promise chain.

If you throw an error or return a promise that is rejected from the error handler of the `then()` method, only then `catch()` method's callback function will be invoked.

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
Promise.reject(123)
.then(
  val => console.log(val),
  error => { throw eror }
)
.catch(error => console.log("inside catch method"));
```

Think of the `catch()` method as a global error handler for all the preceding promises in the promise chain whereas the error handler for the `then()` method is *only* executed if the original promise, on which `then()` method is called on, gets rejected.

Comment: so if there is no possibility of error occurring in `onResolved` on `onRejected` handlers, there is no use of `catch` block?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If there is no possible unhandled promise rejection, then you don't need the `catch()` method. Having said that, using `catch()` method is more common than using two-argument version of `then()` method and i would suggest to use the `catch()` method unless you really need to use the two-argument version of `then()` method.